# Can I restrict my object parameter to real class objects?

Tags: c#, object, parameters, where-clause

I have this c# class with a method signature:

```
public class SomeContainerClass {

public static SomeClass Mthod(object obj, string otherparameter = "test") 
{
}

}
```

The obj parameter should be a class not a boxed primitive. Now I want to prevent compile time that I make the mistake of doing e.g. this: SomeContainerClass.Mthod("astring");

Is that somehow possible? It would be something like:

Mthod(object obj, string otherparameter = "test")  where obj : class

but that does not comile

Comment: Are you looking for generics? `public static SomeClass Mthod<T>(T obj, string otherparameter = "test") where T:class`?

Comment: @Steeeve `string` is a class in C# so that will not do what the OP wants

Comment: What exactly does `Mthod` do? Why do you need to restrict it so you can't pass in a string?

Comment: @DavidG yes, you are right. But maybe the where clause can be restricted to some interface instead of class, so the question is, what type of objects are allowed?

Comment: @Steeeve Yeah, that's why I asked the question of what OP ios trying to actually do.

Comment: It gets the key value from classes, entities. But the key can have all sorts of names, 'id', 'key', 'identifier'. So the signature is object, name-of-key, and the default for the second parameter is the most used name of the identifying member.

Comment: I already like your answer Steeeve at least it prevents of using an integer if my key is an integer. That also happens, so it is already useful for me.

Comment: It seems like you can utilize expressions. If first parameter is object and second parameter is the name of property on that object, then instead you can accept expression and pass it like this: `Mthod<YourEntity>(x => x.SomeProperty)`

Comment: @MarcW If you can create a (dummy) interface implemented by your entities, you can use that interface in the where clause.